# Flutter web stopped working and just shows a blank white screen

Tags: flutter

I had flutter web working perfectly fine and went back to work on the android app and after a while I decided to work on web again and suddenly nothing works on web anymore and whenever i try to run the web app its just a blank white screen :(

here's my debug console :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:52693/JzjWEYSv8vE=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52693/JzjWEYSv8vE=/ws
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52693/JzjWEYSv8vE=/ws
window.flutterWebRenderer is now deprecated.
Use engineInitializer.initializeEngine(config) instead.
See: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/initialization
The webOnlyAssetManager getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `assetManager` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
The webOnlyAssetManager getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `assetManager` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
WARNING: found an existing <meta name="viewport"> tag. Flutter Web uses its own viewport configuration for better compatibility with Flutter. This tag will be replaced.
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/io_patch.dart 244:5                   _operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform_impl.dart 56:40                                          get operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 83:44                                               get operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1430:8  get
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 161:46                                              get isIOS
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1430:8  get
packages/stripe_platform_interface/src/method_channel_stripe.dart 643:33          create
packages/stripe_platform_interface/src/stripe_platform_interface.dart 12:72       get _instance
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1430:8  get
packages/stripe_platform_interface/src/stripe_platform_interface.dart 17:41       get instance
packages/flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart 672:35                                    get _platform
packages/flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart 679:20                                    markNeedsSettings
packages/flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart 25:5                                      set publishableKey
packages/book_door/main.dart 62:10                                                main$
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 846:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 875:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 647:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 529:22                                             <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 846:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 875:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 647:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 721:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7                <fn>
```

i think this is the error that we are trying to fix but i am not sure how

```
window.flutterWebRenderer is now deprecated.
Use engineInitializer.initializeEngine(config) instead.
```

thank you in advance!

I have tried changing the renderer and also changing `<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">` in index.html but it didnt work

Comment: This is your error: `Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem`. Using `Platform` is not supported on web.

The usage/error is coming from the flutter_stripe package. Did you add that package since the last time you ran web? What version of flutter_stripe are you using?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, You are right I just updated the stripe package to the latest version 10.0.0 how can solve this?

Comment: Hey again, I just went back to the flutter_stripe package latest update documentation and it says that since the latest update you have to include the flutter_stripe_web package for it to work on web! it now works just fine thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Great, glad it's working!

Comment: You should consider posting what worked for you as an answer below and accept it so that others can see that your question was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @clavum so I just went back to the flutter_stripe package latest update documentation and it says that since the latest update you have to include the flutter_stripe_web package for it to work on web! it now works just fine thanks for pointing that out

Comment: This answer should have been a comment.